# Copy text on click and display small popup afterwards - extending the code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I need a little script that will allow me to copy text string on click *without a button*.

I found this code:

```
function copy(that){
var inp =document.createElement('input');
document.body.appendChild(inp)
inp.value =that.textContent
inp.select();
document.execCommand('copy',false);
inp.remove();
}
```

The code copies a text on click, but it doesn't show any message. I would like to modify it a little so when user click on text it will be copied and show a little popup message for 2-3 (then it should dissapear by itself) seconds saying that the text has been copied to clipboard. Does anyone have any idea how to modify the code that way?

`<p onclick="copy(this)">example text</p>` - that's how it recognizes which code to copy.

Comment: Make sure you insert your copy function as JavaScript and not as PHP.

Comment: The code here is Javascript and jquery's `functions.php` is meant for defining PHP functions. The two languages are not compatible, hence the syntax error. Javascript needs to be added inside a `<script>` tag in the HTML of your site, or in a `.js` file, referenced in the HTML as something along the lines of `<script src="myScript.js"></script>`.

Comment: Please update your question to include the contents of your `functions.php` file so we can help you debug it. Sounds like you just pasted that code in there which would explain the error you're seeing but we won't know for sure unless we see the code.

Comment: Thank you guys, my bad. I pasted the code in single.php with <script> tags and it works flawlessly. Now I just need to modify the code to show the popup I mentioned. Does anyone have any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this function will help you :

```
copy(){
input  = $(this).val();
document.execCommand('copy',false,input);

$(this).next('text copied');

setTimeout(function(){$(this).next().remove();}, 2000);
}
```

Remember that u must create a tag where u will display the message next to the input tag

Comment: Thank you! Can you just tell me where should I paste the code? Maybe should I mix it up with the one I provided? Sorry for silly questions, I'm still learning.

Comment: No problem u should copy it in the footer of the page after importing jQuery library in the footer of the page after closing the body tag...

Comment: Hmm, I still don't get the "after importing jQuery library in the footer" part. Could you please show me how the full code should look like?

Answer (score 0):

Hey there is a full example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" onclick="copy(this)" value="malek gorchene"></input>
    <!-- this p is for the notification -->
    <p></p>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


    function copy(elem){
        input  = $(elem).val();
        elem.select();//Select the text in the input element 
        document.execCommand('copy');//copy it 

        $(elem).next().text('text copied');

        setTimeout(function(){$(elem).next().text('');}, 2000);//
    }


</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! :) The code you posted works awesome, but I have two questions:

1. Here's how it looks right now - https://screenshots.firefox.com/M9QwnGKhmflTrD6L/test2.gromocje.pl - how can I remove the whole form? I'd love to have just text.

2. I would love to have different text for each post to copy. The code I posted in my first post used to work like that - I pasted it in single.php and then I could paste <p onclick="copy(this)">example text</p> in Wordpress post editor and have different text every time. Is there a way to make it work like that?

Answer (score 0):

Hey there that's the first question but i don't get the second :

```js
function copy(elem){
  if($(elem).text()){
    var dummy = document.createElement("textarea");
      document.body.appendChild(dummy);
      dummy.value = $(elem).text();
      dummy.select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
      document.body.removeChild(dummy);
  }else{
    input  = $(elem).val();
    elem.select();//Select the text in the input element 
    document.execCommand('copy');//copy it 
  }



  $(elem).next().text('text copied');

  setTimeout(function(){$(elem).next().text('');}, 2000);//
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onclick="copy(this)" value="click me"></input>
<p></p>
<p onclick="copy(this)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<!-- this p is for the notification -->
<p></p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it works like a charm. I managed to modify it by myself (the second question). I have last two questions:


1.When I want the click-to-copy code work, I just paste the following code in post editor: <p onclick="copy(this)">example post</p>. The problem is that the <p> tag makes the text jump to the next paragraph. I'd love no gaps there, so I tried <b> instead but unfortunately the code stops working when I do that. Do you have any idea how can I make it work the way I need (the text needs to be in the same paragraph as the rest of the sentence).

Comment: 2. How can I style the popup saying that the text has been copied (add background, change color)? I tried to add a class here: "<script class="example-class" type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
but it doesn't work that way :/

Comment: Yes when i back home i'll send you the code... But if you want to boost your skills you should try and read documents :p

Comment: Thank you! I can't wait :) I do that all the time, but sometimes for me its best to learn (experiment) on already existing code. :-)

Comment: As you like bro ;)

Comment: Hey bro! Are you home by any chance? :)